# MySql Crystal Report ASP.Net with C# web site not executing my report? I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate on my 64-bit laptop

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I am trying to play with MySql with C# ASP Dotnet and Crystal Reports.
My Default page is looks like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<CR:CrystalReportPartsViewer ID="CrystalReportPartsViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" />
    <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server" ></CR:CrystalReportSource>
    <Report FileName="TestReport.rpt"></Report>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code behind default.aspx.cs page:

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Web;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
using MySql.Data;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
GeneralMethods gm = new GeneralMethods();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ReportDocument myReport = new ReportDocument();
        DataSet myData = new DataSet();
        MySqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter();
            var sql = "SELECT sno,dept_lbl,is_active FROM departments";

            myAdapter.SelectCommand = gm.getRecordSet(sql);
            myAdapter.Fill(myData);

           if(System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(@"./testRpt.rpt"))){
                myReport.Load(Server.MapPath(@"./testRpt.rpt"));
                myReport.SetDataSource(myData);
                CrystalReportPartsViewer1.ReportSource = myReport;
            }
            else{
                this.msg.InnerText  = "File not found";
            }       
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {

    }

}
}
```

My .xsd file is as under:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="postCodeCombo" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/postCodeCombo.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/postCodeCombo.xsd" xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/postCodeCombo.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xs:element name="Document">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="PostCodes">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="sno" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" />
     <xs:element name="dept_lbl" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
             <xs:element name="is_active" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Everything working fine like record loading from table etc but once the comipler reach to the code in code behind i.e.

```
myReport.Load(@"./testRpt.rpt");
```

It throws an error that is : **"Load report failed"**
I have created **testRpt.rpt** file and placed here in the **root** folder. I don't know whats going wrong?

Comment: Bin folder? "~/testRpt.rpt" points to **root** folder. Change path in your code or move your file...

Comment: ok i have moved my file from bin to the root folder now it can find the .rpt file but still there is nothing to print on the page?